# Type asserting errors in go

Tags: go

I am making a small function to check an `error` against some types and decide (depending on the error type) whether some retries are worth it.

I have created my own `temporary` interface to type assert all `net/http` errors that implement this interface (which however is unexported and thus I am declaring it my code as well)

```golang
type temporary interface {
    Temporary() bool
}
```

So, I want to retry when there is a net/http error implementing the `temporary` interface, as well in case the error is one of the following types: `io.EOF`, `io.ErrUnexpectedEOF` of `ErrTimeoutExceeded`

where

```golang
var ErrTimeoutExceeded = errors.New("timeout exceeded")
```

however the following switch statement

```golang
func isWorthRetrying(err error) bool {
    switch e := err.(type) {
    case temporary:
        return true
    case io.EOF:
        return true
    case io.ErrUnexpectedEOF:
        return true
    case ErrTimeoutExceeded:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

errors out in all statements (except the one type asserting against `temporary`)

with the error e.g.

> io.EOF (type error) is not a type

What does this mean?

Comment: `io.EOF` is a value, not a type. `switch e := err.(type)` is a type switch for asserting the types in the cases. You are mixing up type switch and normal (expression) switch. You need two separate switches, one for types one for the error values.

Comment: Do a type switch with only one case for temporary, and in default do an expression switch where you check against the error values.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expression_switches and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches are two different switch statements.

Comment: ok thanks if you d like post it as a regular answer so that I can accept / upvote

Comment: user cd1 already posted an equivalent answer, you can accept that.

Comment: Please take a look at the new error functionality introduced in Go 1.13 which simplifies and clarifies this sort of error checking code: https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#error_wrapping and https://golang.org/pkg/errors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your switch statement, you're checking against `err.(type)`, which is a *type*. The values `io.EOF`, `io.ErrUnexpectedEOF` and `ErrTimeoutExceeded` aren't types, they're objects. You can't check if a type *is* an object (different things); however, you can check if an object *is of* a type.

You can use the following code to check for both scenarios:

```
func isWorthRetrying(err error) bool {
        switch err.(type) {
        case temporary:
                return true
        default:
                switch err {
                case io.EOF:
                        return true
                case io.ErrUnexpectedEOF:
                        return true
                case ErrTimeoutExceeded:
                        return true
                default:
                        return false
                }
        }
}
```

EDIT: thanks to Adrian's comment, we can also write this function using the new `errors.Is`, if you're using Go 1.13+:

```
func isWorthRetrying(err error) bool {
        switch err.(type) {
        case temporary:
                return true
        default:
                return errors.Is(err, io.EOF) ||
                        errors.Is(err, io.ErrUnexpectedEOF) ||
                        errors.Is(err, ErrTimeoutExceeded)
        }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the new error functionality introduced in Go 1.13 which simplifies and clarifies this sort of error checking code: golang.org/doc/go1.13#error_wrapping and golang.org/pkg/errors